# I have a gree mini split 18k btu

Tags: hvac

I have a gree mini split 18k btu, there is 4 wires for communication. I dont see any spot for line wire on condenser, indoor unit has cord w/ 3 wires? Do some plug in from inside or have wires that run from indoor to outside for power?

Comment: The Fine Manual: Page 26-28, though they do specify that it should be done by a "qualified electrical contractor" so your warranty may be void if you DIY: https://greeonline.com/upload/products/hansol/hansol-downloads/Hansol%20GWH18%2024%2028k%20Owners%20Manual.pdf

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.